# what is the Difference between these Marketplaces?

Tags: azure, azure-marketplace

I am planning to create a SaaS application and publish it in Azure marketplace, but I have a query.

I would like to know what is the difference between **Marketplace** within **Azure Management Portal**, and **Marketplace** available at this location https://datamarket.azure.com/home

I have been searching the web for quite a while to know about any difference but couldn't find any.

Also I found that most of the applications are not part of **Marketplace** within **Azure Management Portal**. Are there any guidelines or rules your app should follow to be listed in there?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a product offered by Microsoft, not about code.

Comment: Have you tried asking your local Microsoft Developer Evangelist?